# How to add mysql / mysqli module to php 5.5 in Docker?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, php-5.5

I'm trying to connect PHP to MySQL but getting this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1568
```

I'm trying to add mysql / mysqli extensions with Dockerfile below, but it seems it not work.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-55-apache
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: php:5.5-apache
    volumes:
      - /Websites/wordpress/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8000:80
      - 3306:3306
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.5-apache

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysql mysqli

RUN printf 'log_errors = On\nerror_log = /dev/stderr\n' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

It installs it correctly, looking by build output, but after that directory /usr/src/php/ext/mysql doesnt exist and there so mysql/mysqli installed:

```
root@8701d8632493:/var/www/html# find / -name "*mysql*"
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_charset.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_structs.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/php_mysqlnd_config.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_net.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_result.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_priv.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_enum_n_def.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_result_meta.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_wireprotocol.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_block_alloc.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/php_mysqlnd.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysql_float_to_double.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_statistics.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_ext_plugin.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_libmysql_compat.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_debug.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_portability.h
/usr/local/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_alloc.h
```

Docker 3.1, macOS

Comment: Just curious , does MYSQL Workbench happen to work inside a container?  I can't imagine how painful being forced to do inline mysql  coding would be otherwise, so I suspect it does, but if anyone can confirm would be nice to know.

Comment: @easleyfixed I'm planning to connect it from outside of container

Comment: That is even better, good to know its a thing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the image of the container to `php:5.6-apache-stretch`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache-stretch
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli
RUN printf 'extension=php_mysqli.so\nerror_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE' >> /usr/local/etc/php.ini
```